# check and uncheck a dynamic checkboxlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this checkboxlist that it's items fills with linq datasource now I want to check some of these check boxes programmatically...
this is my checkboxlist:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource2" DataTextField="ProjectGroupTitle" DataValueField="ProjectGroupID"></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

and this is my code trying to check some of these check boxes so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Text == j.ProjectGroupTitle)
                            {
                                CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected = true;
                            }
                        }
```

when I checked this piece of code in debug mode I realized that CheckBoxList1.Items.Count value is 0 which is odd as I have multiple value in my database that linq datasource is responsible for fetching them for checkboxlist...
could someone help me fix this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to test your code in page render:-

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource2" DataTextField="ProjectGroupTitle" DataValueField="ProjectGroupID" OnDataBound="SelectCheckbox"></asp:CheckBoxList> 

 public void SelectCheckbox(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Text == j.ProjectGroupTitle)
                            {
                                CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected = true;
                            }
                        }
    }
```

Comment: may I ask are you trying to check the if statement? or my checkboxlist to be correct?.....if it is for checking checkboxlist I'm kind of sure that it's correct....in matter of fact if I want to make my situation a little more clear I should say I have this gridview in which there is a button that has the id of the gridview row by clicking that button and the page would direct to another view of a multiview which there is my checkboxlist to edit so I should kind of show the options that user had chosen before for him to edit,,,

Comment: check CheckBoxList1.Items.Count here

Comment: @sara.y i modified my answer, if your query return some result this code must work.

Comment: is there a way that I make sure databound occur via c# instead of asp.net?...since checkboxlist is in one view of multiview and it should change a number of time with this code without refreshing the page

Comment: thanks it was totally about the databind...I code checkboxlist.databind() before my code in c# and there it was...

Answer (score 3):

Check the `Request.Form` variables while debugging. And please provide as with more information. (is it an `aspx` or an `ascx` code behind. is there any update Panel ...)

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Check your page_load method. Probably your checkboxList dataSource count =0. Test if (isPostBack)

Comment: my checkboxlist works fine when I'm not trying to check it programmatically...so the data source is not the problem :(

Comment: @Med.Amine.Touil this should be a comment.